# Anonymous function name not getting displayed

Tags: javascript

When I define a function as following I'm able to retrieve the name of the function and no of parameters.

```js
    let func = function(arg1, arg2){
     console.log("I am a function");
    }
    console.log("Function name : " + func.name);
    console.log("No of parameters : " + func.length);
```

But if I use another function to retrieve a anonymous function in a variable then the function name is displayed as empty string.

```js
let func = function(){
     return function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
      console.log("Nested anonymous function");
     };
    }
    let func1 = func();
    console.log("Function name : " + func1.name); // "func1" expected
    console.log("No of parameters : " + func1.length);
```

So my doubt is in both the cases anonymous functions are getting assigned to some variable. But in first case it abopts variable's name as function's name. But in second case it doesn't. What is the reason of this peculiar behaviour?

Comment: @Utsav Patel Yes that is the question. It is not adopting variable's name

Comment: Fundamentally you have an *anonymous function*. Expecting it to have a name is weird. It’s an interesting question why these two cases behave differently. But this should not really surprise you in the first place.

Comment: @deceze As my understanding whenever we assign an anonymous function to a variable that function adopts its name property from variable's name, in first case it is working fine but in second what is happening? Please refer to http://javascript.info/function-object

Comment: since in javascript a function is an object, you are trying to creat an objcet that returning another object, and in this case, you are returning an unnamed object so compiler doesn't know what is the object's name

Comment: The behavior you seem to expect would be `a.name == 'a'`, i.e. the name of the function is always the name of the variable it’s currently assigned to. That’s not the case, and would be rather useless behavior. I’ll try to write a longer answer later.

Comment: See what I am thinking is that in the first case when we are assigning anonymous function to a variable, It is like a initialisation of variable but in second case when we are returning the anonymous function first that function get assigned to some temporary variable just to make it a returnable component so from this temporary variable it is getting the empty name.
Am I making any sense?

Comment: Yes. Seems to be the case.  Initially, these `let func = function()` functions did not get names too but were later added as it made debugging hard to a point where people avoided anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Variables and methods can infer the name of an anonymous function from
>   its **syntactic position** (new in ECMAScript 2015).
>
> ```
> let f = function() {};
> let object = {
>   someMethod: function() {}
> };
>
> console.log(f.name); // "f"
> console.log(object.someMethod.name); // "someMethod"
> ```
>
> <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names</sub>

Note the highlight: a name can be inferred from its *syntactic position*. Meaning, if the function appears in the source code with a left-hand side expression that lets the engine infer a name, it will do so. However, in your case the left-hand side is `return`, which does not allow to infer any name. Javascript will *not* track it through being returned from the function and assigned somewhere in the caller, so your anonymous function remains anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an experiment that supplements your theory. if you name the function being returned by `func`, `func1.name` is set to that name. I think it's safe to conclude that function names are only set when initialising the function with the `function ...() { ... }` syntax

```js
let func = function(){
     return function func1(arg1, arg2, arg3){
      console.log("Nested anonymous function");
     };
    }
    let func1 = func();
    console.log("Function name : " + func1.name); // "func1" set
    console.log("No of parameters : " + func1.length);
```